# Lotus notes plugin to intercept outgoing emails (JAVA)

Tags: java, plugins, lotus-notes

I need to develop a Lotus Notes plug-in that adds some UI to Lotus Notes main UI and does the following when user creates & sends an email:

1. Intercept the outgoing email to see if there are any attachments in email.
2. If there is any attachment found in email, cancel sending the email.
3. Manipulate the attachments of email and then send the email again (by calling some Notes API)

Is this doable in Lotus Notes plug-ins?

Thanks & regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Comment: I suggest you look into server mail rules, how much they can do for you. Otherwise, if you want a plugin you'd have to develop a DLL based on the Extension Manager calls.

Comment: D.Bugger, can you please provide some help on how I can get a start on what you said? Can I add the UI as well using such a DLL (in C / C# or whatever)?

Comment: Also, I need to make it run on MAC as well, but the DLLs are for windows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.ibm.NotesJava.agents;

import lotus.domino.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MyJavaAgent extends AgentBase {
   //Main metho which is called by lotus notes
    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            // (Your code goes here)
            Name n = session.createName(agentContext.getEffectiveUserName());
            String st = n.getCommon();
            Log log=session.createLog("JAVA_AGENT");
            log.openFileLog("JAVA_AGENT.log");
            MessageBox mb = new MessageBox();
            try{
                log.logAction("");
                log.logAction("******************************Starting JAVA AGENT ************************");
                log.logAction("Hello " + st + "!"); 
                log.logAction("Executing JavaAgentTest with Agent: "+agentContext.getCurrentAgent().getName());
                Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
                //System.out.println("Loading emaildetails.properties file from following location:C:\\Program Files\\Lotus\\Notes\\framework\\emaildetails.properties");
                log.logAction("Loading emaildetails.properties file from following location:C:\\Program Files\\Lotus\\Notes\\framework\\emaildetails.properties");
                Properties pro = new Properties();
                File fil = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Lotus\\Notes\\framework\\emaildetails.properties");
                //***********LOGIC*********
                DocumentCollection coll=agentContext.getUnprocessedDocuments();
                Document doc=coll.getFirstDocument();
                //get  input from user about the process area 
}
}

/************************Library Code ***********************************/
/* 
 * The MessageBox class allows you to create simple message boxes
 * using only the java.awt classes. All you have to do is create an instance
 * of a MessageBox and use it to call the doOkCancelDialog or the
 * doInputBox methods. You can use a single MessageBox instance to
 * create multiple dialogs.
 *
 * This class has been implemented here as an inner class, but there's
 * no reason why it couldn't be a class all by itself. The functionality to
 * create buttons and messageboxes has been modularized, so it should
 * be easy for you to add your own methods to this class, or make global
 * modifications as you desire.
 *
 * The only really complicated/weird thing I had to do was to write and
 * include the MultiLineLabel class, which is included towards the end
 * of this class as an inner class. Read the comments associated with
 * that class to see what's going on there.
 *
 * Make sure you import java.awt.* and java.awt.event.*
 *
 * Julian Robichaux -- http://www.nsftools.com
 */
class MessageBox {

    public final int NO_ACTION = -1;
    public final int CANCEL_ACTION = 0;
    public final int OK_ACTION = 1;
    int actionCode = NO_ACTION;

    Frame parent;
    Dialog msgbox;
    MultiLineLabel msglabel;        // our custom class, defined later
    Panel buttons;
    Button ok, cancel;
    TextField textbox;
    Choice dropdown;
    List multilist;

    public MessageBox ()  {
        // this is the invisible Frame we'll be using to call all of our Dialogs
        parent = new Frame();
    }

    public void dispose ()  {
        // use this when you're ready to clean up
        try { msgbox.dispose(); }  catch (Exception e)  {}
        try { parent.dispose(); }  catch (Exception e)  {}
    }

    /* 
     * This method will create a simple dialog box with a title, a message,
     * and Ok/Cancel buttons. It will halt execution of your program until
     * one of the buttons is clicked, and it will return either OK_ACTION
     * if the Ok button is clicked, or CANCEL_BUTTON if the Cancel
     * button is clicked.
     */
    public int doOkCancelDialog (String title, String message)  {
        actionCode = NO_ACTION;
        try  {
            // create the messagebox
            msgbox = new Dialog(parent, title, true);
            msgbox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // create the label
            initMsglabel(message);
            msgbox.add("North", msglabel);

            // create the OK and Cancel buttons
            buttons = new Panel();
            buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            initOkButton();
            buttons.add(ok);
            initCancelButton();
            buttons.add(cancel);
            msgbox.add("South", buttons);

            // display everything (the system will wait until a button is pressed
            // before returning)
            displayMsgbox();
            msgbox.dispose();       // just in case the ActionListeners didn't fire...
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
        }

        return actionCode;
    }

    /* 
     * This method will create a dialog box that allows the user to enter
     * text into a field. It also has a title, a message, and Ok/Cancel buttons, 
     * and will halt execution of your program until one of the buttons is
     * clicked or the user enters text into the field and presses "Enter".
     * If the user clicks the Ok button or enters text and presses "Enter",
     * then the text in the field will be returned; otherwise, this method will
     * return null (which usually indicates that the user clicked Cancel).
     */
    public String doInputBox (String title, String message, String defaultText)  {
        actionCode = NO_ACTION;
        try  {
            // create the messagebox
            msgbox = new Dialog(parent, title, true);
            msgbox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // create the label
            initMsglabel(message);
            msgbox.add("North", msglabel);

            // create the text field
            initTextbox(defaultText);
            msgbox.add("Center", textbox);

            // create the OK and Cancel buttons
            buttons = new Panel();
            buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            initOkButton();
            buttons.add(ok);
            initCancelButton();
            buttons.add(cancel);
            msgbox.add("South", buttons);

            // display everything (the system will wait until a button is pressed
            // before returning)
            displayMsgbox();
            msgbox.dispose();       // just in case the ActionListeners didn't fire...
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
        }

        if (actionCode == OK_ACTION)
            return textbox.getText();
        else
            return null;
    }

    /* 
     * This method will create a dialog box that allows the user to select from
     * a dropdown list. It also has a title, a message, and Ok/Cancel buttons, 
     * and will halt execution of your program until one of the buttons is
     * clicked. If the user clicks the Ok button then the text in the field will be 
     * returned; otherwise, this method will return null (which usually indicates 
     * that the user clicked Cancel).
     */
    public String doDropdownBox (String title, String message, String[] selections)  {
        actionCode = NO_ACTION;
        try  {
            // create the messagebox
            msgbox = new Dialog(parent, title, true);
            msgbox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // create the label
            initMsglabel(message);
            msgbox.add("North", msglabel);

            // create the dropdown box
            initDropdown(selections);
            msgbox.add("Center", dropdown);

            // create the OK and Cancel buttons
            buttons = new Panel();
            buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            initOkButton();
            buttons.add(ok);
            initCancelButton();
            buttons.add(cancel);
            msgbox.add("South", buttons);

            // display everything (the system will wait until a button is pressed
            // before returning)
            displayMsgbox();
            msgbox.dispose();       // just in case the ActionListeners didn't fire...
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
        }

        if (actionCode == OK_ACTION)
            return dropdown.getSelectedItem();
        else
            return null;
    }

    /* 
     * This method will create a dialog box that allows the user to select from
     * a list of options (use the allowMultiSelect parameter to indicate whether
     * the user can select multiple items from the list [true] or just one [false]). 
     * It also has a title, a message, and Ok/Cancel buttons, and will halt 
     * execution of your program until one of the buttons is clicked. If the user 
     * clicks the Ok button then the text in the field will be returned; otherwise, 
     * this method will return null (which usually indicates that the user clicked 
     * Cancel or didn't select anything).
     */
    public String[] doMultilistBox (String title, String message, String[] selections, boolean allowMultiSelect)  {
        actionCode = NO_ACTION;
        try  {
            // create the messagebox
            msgbox = new Dialog(parent, title, true);
            msgbox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // create the label
            initMsglabel(message);
            msgbox.add("North", msglabel);

            // create the multilist field
            initMultilist(4, allowMultiSelect, selections);
            msgbox.add("Center", multilist);

            // create the OK and Cancel buttons
            buttons = new Panel();
            buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            initOkButton();
            buttons.add(ok);
            initCancelButton();
            buttons.add(cancel);
            msgbox.add("South", buttons);

            // display everything (the system will wait until a button is pressed
            // before returning)
            displayMsgbox();
            msgbox.dispose();       // just in case the ActionListeners didn't fire...
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
        }

        if ((actionCode == OK_ACTION) && 
            (java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(multilist.getSelectedItems()) > 0))
            return multilist.getSelectedItems();
        else
            return null;
    }

    /*
     * The private methods below are simply reusable modular functions for
     * creating various elements that may appear in a MessageBox dialog.
     * They make it easier to write new public methods that create different
     * kinds of dialogs, and also allow you to make global changes to all your
     * dialog components pretty easily.
     */
     private void initMsglabel (String message)  {
        // the actual message in the MessageBox (using the custom
        // MultiLineLabel class, included below)
        msglabel = new MultiLineLabel(message);
     }

    private void initOkButton ()  {
        // the OK button
        ok = new Button("OK");
        ok.addActionListener( new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                actionCode = OK_ACTION;
                msgbox.dispose();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void initCancelButton ()  {
        // the Cancel button
        cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener( new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                actionCode = CANCEL_ACTION;
                msgbox.dispose();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void initTextbox (String defaultText)  {
        // the field that allows a user to enter text in an InputBox
        textbox = new TextField(defaultText, 40);
        // the ActionListener here will get called if the user presses "Enter"
        textbox.addActionListener( new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                actionCode = OK_ACTION;
                msgbox.dispose();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void initDropdown (String[] selections)  {
        // a dropdown box that allows a user to select from a list of
        // multiple items
        dropdown = new Choice();
        for (int i = 0; i < java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(selections); i++)
            dropdown.add(selections[i]);
    }

    private void initMultilist (int numOfLines, boolean allowMultiSelect, String[] selections)  {
        // a multiple selection box that allows a user to select one or 
        // more items. numOfLines indicates how many lines should be
        // visible at a time, allowMultiSelect is a boolean value indicating 
        // whether or not the user should be allowed to select more than
        // one item from the list, and selections is an array of Strings that 
        // is used to populate the selection box
        multilist = new List(numOfLines, allowMultiSelect);
        for (int i = 0; i < java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(selections); i++)
            multilist.add(selections[i]);
    }

    private void displayMsgbox ()  {
        // once all of the components have been added to a dialog,
        // use this method to display it
        Dimension d = msgbox.getToolkit().getScreenSize();
        msgbox.setLocation(d.width/3, d.height/3);      // center the dialog (sort of)
        msgbox.pack();                      // organize all its components
        msgbox.setResizable(false);     // make sure the user can't resize it
        msgbox.toFront();                   // give it focus
        msgbox.setVisible(true);                // and display it
    }

    /*
     * Okay, this is a pain, but java.awt doesn't natively have a Label-type class
     * that allows you to display text that's more than one line. So I had to write one
     * myself. The class below is a modification of some code from the fantastic
     * book, "Java in a Nutshell".
     *
     * The big change I made was to allow this multi-line label to have a fixed width,
     * so the Label wouldn't fly off the screen if you had a big paragraph of text to
     * display. The width is specified in "columns", which I defined as the width of
     * the letter "X" in whatever font is being used. The text that you add to the label
     * is automatically split into chunks that are no longer than the number of columns
     * specified (you'll see the code to do this in the parseLabel method).
     *
     * This sample implementation is an inner class of the MessageBox class, although
     * it could also be a separate class all by itself. I made it an inner class to make it
     * easier to copy and paste everything from one agent to another.
     *
     * Julian Robichaux -- http://www.nsftools.com
     */
    class MultiLineLabel extends Canvas  {
        // a custom class that will display a text label at a fixed width across
        // multiple lines
        // (modification of MultiLineLabel class from "Java in a Nutshell")
        String label;
        String[] lines;
        int rows = 1;
        int cols = 40;
        int margin = 6;
        int rowHeight;
        int lineAscent;
        int maxWidth;

        public MultiLineLabel (String text)  {
            // create a label with the default width
            label = text;
        }

        public MultiLineLabel (String text, int columns)  {
            // create a label with the specified number of "columns" (where a column
            // is the width of "X" in the font that we're using)
            if (columns > 0)
                cols = columns;
            label = text;
        }

        protected void measure ()  {
            // get the global values we use in relation to our current font
            FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(this.getFont());
            if (fm == null)
                return;

            rowHeight = fm.getHeight();
            lineAscent = fm.getAscent();
            maxWidth = fm.stringWidth("X") * cols;
        }

        private int stringWidth (String text)  {
            // calculate the width of a String using our current font
            FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(this.getFont());
            if (fm == null)
                return 0;
            return fm.stringWidth(text);
        }

        public Font getFont ()  {
            // return the font that we're currently using
            return super.getFont();
        }

        public void setFont (Font f)  {
            // change the font that we're currently using, and redraw the
            // label with the new font
            super.setFont(f);
            repaint();
        }

        public void addNotify ()  {
            // automatically invoked after our label/Canvas is created but 
            // before it's displayed (FontMetrics aren't available until
            // super.addNotify() has been called)
            super.addNotify();
            measure();
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize ()  {
            // called by the LayoutManager to find out how big we want to be
            if (lines == null)
                setText(label);
            return new Dimension(maxWidth + (2 * margin), (rows * rowHeight) + (2 * margin));
        }

        public Dimension getMinimumSize ()  {
            // called by the LayoutManager to find out what our bare minimum
            // size requirements are
            if (lines == null)
                setText(label);
            return new Dimension(maxWidth, (rows * rowHeight));
        }

        public void setText (String text)  {
            // change the text we're using for this label
            label = text;
            parseLabel();
        }

        private void parseLabel ()  {
            // parses the text we want to display in the label, so that the lines[]
            // variable contains lines of text that are no wider than maxWidth
            String token, word;
            StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer("");
            StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer("");

            // do an initial measurement, to make sure we have maxWidth
            measure();
            rows = 0;

            // we'll be tokenizing the label String twice, first at every end-of-line
            // character ('\n') and then at every space (if the lines are too long), 
            // in order to generate an StringBuffer of proper length lines, all 
            // separated by \n
            java.util.StringTokenizer st1 = new java.util.StringTokenizer(label, "\n", false);
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens())  {
                token = st1.nextToken();
                if (stringWidth(token) <= maxWidth)  {
                    // if the whole line is shorter than the maxWidth allowed, we can
                    // just add this line to the buffer and get the next one
                    rows++;
                    msg.append(token + "\n");
                }  else  {
                    // if the line was too long, we'll have to break it up manually by
                    // tokenizing the line at every space and adding words together
                    // one by one until we have a line that's greater than maxWidth;
                    // then we can add that shorter line to the buffer and keep doing
                    // that until we're out of words
                    java.util.StringTokenizer st2 = new java.util.StringTokenizer(token, " ", false);
                    while (st2.hasMoreTokens())  {
                        word = st2.nextToken();
                        if ((stringWidth(line.toString()) + stringWidth(word)) > maxWidth)  {
                            rows++;
                            msg.append(line.toString() + "\n");
                            line.setLength(0);
                            line.append(word + " ");
                        }  else  {
                            line.append(word + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    // after we've run out of words, add any remaining text to the buffer, too
                    if (line.length() > 0)  {
                            rows++;
                            msg.append(line.toString() + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            // once we're done, split the buffer into the lines[] array
            java.util.StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer(msg.toString(), "\n");
            lines = new String[rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                lines[i] = st.nextToken();

        }

        public void paint (Graphics g)  {
            // draw the actual label to the screen, with space around the edges
            // based on the margins we've specified (for some reason, we have to
            // call setLabel instead of just parseText here in order to get the size
            // right, which is a little redundant, but whatever works...)
            int y;
            setText(label);
            Dimension d = this.getSize();
            y = lineAscent + (d.height - (rows * rowHeight)) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++, y += rowHeight)
                g.drawString(lines[i], margin, y);
        }

    }
}// end of the MultiLineLabel class
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I want to start a thread to process my email (like uploading attachments somewhere and then adding links to the body) after agent has got the document from notes send event. This is because the send event waits for agent to exit (UI hangs because my process could take long) and any threads I start are also terminated (which is natural as the main program exits).
Please suggest any alternative approach. I am thinking to bring RMI inside, so java agent would hand it over to an other java program that listens as RMI server. Would that be fine?

Thanks & regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Comment: well seems that the problem is getting complicated..try for the RMI though its not a good solution as it will further complicate the process..and if not handled properly then u may get error which will be hard to detect and fix..performance may still be any issue with RMI..

Comment: I have found a workaround for this. I am able to remove attachments using vb script inside the Querysend event of Message form. It works fine.
Now there is one question about the template. If user replaces the application design using my template, and later on, suppose, he replaces the design with someone else's template, will my changes be overwritten? Will my template still be working? I am assuming that if the latter template inherits the changes, it should work fine.
Thanks & regards

Comment: If someone else needs to do the same, I am using Source.Document.RemoveItem("$File") to remove the attachments.

Comment: Hi Rajesh,

I am using an external jar file that requires its .properties file to be placed in the working directory. What is the working directory for a lotus notes java agent? I can see the Code, Forms folders in my project hierarchy but can't figure out where to place this file. I don't have access to the source of the jar so I cannot make changes to it.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using java lotus notes API.
Download the examples from here..
 http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#javascraps
Download javascraps.zip file..it has example for maximum API..

To complete ur work u need to create a java agent in lotus notes and then you need to write java code as per your requirement using the java API to get the task done..

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I will get back after trying this.

Comment: Hi Rajesh,

I created an agent in eclipse by adding Notes.jar file in the class path. When I run it, I get "No AgentContext document found for agent.." message.
Can you please guide me with the steps to achieve my above task with the agent?

Comment: are u running the code from eclipse.. ? Dont run it from eclipse inorder to test..Create agent in lotus notes and then run it from Action menu..(make your agent munu driven for testing..)later u can change it to onEmail Sent etc..here is a sample java code..

Comment: Yes I was running from eclipse, now I am running it from Lotus Notes menu option as you said above and it is running fine.

I have a few more questions:

1. How would I configure it to get invoked on email send event? I do not see any outgoing email event option under "Trigger: " in the runtime property.
2. When I call getUnprocessedDocuments(), it returns all the documents from all folders regardless of what is received / sent. How do I differentiate whether a document is waiting to be sent?

best regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Comment: Well,I have created a Notes template. In that template, I have edited the QuerySend event of Message form where I can invoke my java agent.
Now the problem is, I need to remove attachments from the email document and insert my links in its body. When I remove attachments inside my agent code and call send() method on it,Lotus Notes client shows an error "Invalid or non-existent item".
Also, I need the new mail form to be closed and then I want to start a thread from my agent that would manipulate the attachments and then send the email, but my thread is terminated when agent exits.Can u help?